# Is resb 2 equivalent to resw 1?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

In this code:

```
    global _start
section .bss
    v1 resw 1
    v2 resb 2    ;array of 2 chars 
section .text
_start:
    mov word[v1],500
    mov word[v2],500

    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

Is this code correct or not?
Does `word[v1]` work the same way as `word[v2]`?

I'm using NASM on x86-64 Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they both do reserve the same amount of memory (2 bytes), so you can safely access them using `mov word[...], ...`.

Note that this is roughly equal to writing `uint8_t v1[2]` vs. `uint16_t v2[1]` in C.  But NASM doesn't enforce types so every memory reference is like using C `memcpy()` to do strict-aliasing-safe loads or stores that transfer N bytes without caring about the C type of the memory.

I strongly recommend to actually use `resw`, if you plan to use the allocated data as a `word` or an array of `word`s, to avoid confusion and potential bugs.

Comment: It would also be totally fine to consistently use `resb` for everything and just manually multiply by the element size to get sizes in bytes.  NASM doesn't do any magic association between labels and operand-size the way MASM "variables" do.  But yes it's typical for static storage that's only used one way to use `resX` where X is the appropriate element size.